# What's wrong about this function?

Tags: ocaml

```
let minus = function
    | Int.min_value, _ | Int.max_value, _ | _, Int.min_value | _, Int.max_value -> 0
    | x, y -> x - y
```

> Error: Parse error: [module_longident] expected after "." (in
>   [module_longident])

I can't see anything wrong.

I did this in `utop` with `Core.Std` opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int.min_value` and `Int.max_value` are values, not constructors (names of constructors are capitalized, names of values are not).

You can't use values in a pattern matching, you can only use constructors.

The good code is

```
let minus (x, y) =
  if x = Int.min_value
  || x = Int.max_value
  || y = Int.min_value
  || y = Int.max_value
  then
    0
  else
    x - y
```

your wrong code is equivalent to

```
let min_value = -1000000
let max_value = 1000000

let minus = function
| min_value, _ | max_value, _ | _, min_value | _, max_value -> 0
| x, y -> x - y
```

which compiles because it uses correct names (not names from a different module) but produces the wrong result (always 0).